# How can one best visualize two dimensional manifolds in $\mathbb{R^4}$ (more specifically, $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition, surfaces, visualization

I'm trying to "get a picture", so to speak, of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$. One example would be $\left(\dfrac{\cos(u)}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}, \dfrac{\sin(u)}{\sqrt{1+u^2}},\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}, v \right)$, where $-2\pi \leq u \leq 2\pi$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, even though this is a 2-dimensional surface, I haven't found any way to really understand what it looks like. I'm aware this is kind of hard to answer, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can also think about $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ as punctured 3-space, so you could probably get a pretty good picture of your surface.

Comment: $S^2\times\Bbb R$ is the normal line bundle on $S^2$

Comment: Maybe try to plot it in 3d, using the 4th coordinate as color?

Comment: [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d+parametric+plot+((cos+t)%2Fsqrt(1%2Bt%5E2),+sin+t%2Fsqrt(1%2Bt%5E2),+t%2Fsqrt(1%2Bt%5E2)),+t%3D-2pi..2pi) is a graph of your first three coordinates; your surface is just (this) x (real line).

Comment: I see now. I should've picked a better example (see my comment on @ArnaudMortier's answer)

Comment: These examples are all the same computationally; the first three coordinates involve one parameter, and so give a curve; the last coordinate involves a different parameter, so gives a line.  All your surfaces are then (curve from first 3 coordinates) x (image of last coordinate function).

Comment: @SteveD But it's not actually possible to plot them, right?

Comment: You *can* plot them, since (as I mentioned above) this is all happening in punctured 3-space. For example, [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d+parametric+plot+(e%5Es+*+(cos+t)%2Fsqrt(1%2Bt%5E2),+e%5Es+*+sin+t%2Fsqrt(1%2Bt%5E2),+e%5Es+*+t%2Fsqrt(1%2Bt%5E2)),+t%3D-2pi..2pi,s%3D-1..1).  Just multiply your first three coordinates by $e^{f(v)}$.  Again, this relies on identifying $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ with punctured 3-space.

Comment: @SteveD Interesting. But what's the reasoning behind multiplying the first three coordinates by $e^{f(v)}$?

Comment: That just maps your real line to the positive reals, so you don't get multiple ways to specify the same point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ over your surface, so this is a curve drawn on a $2$-sphere, times a real line. You could call this an infinite curtain.

The $z$-value of the curve keeps increasing, so this is a spring with varying radius$^\star$, spiraling around the $z$-axis monotonically, times a real line.

$^\star$The radius is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4\pi^2}}$ at the extremities, goes monotonically up to $1$ (when $z=0$), then symetrically back to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4\pi^2}}$

Comment: Can I do similar things to help me visualize these surfaces when my $z$ value is an arbitrary function $f(v)$? Let's say I wanted to picture the more complicated case: $$\left(\dfrac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^4 + t^2 + e^{2t}}},\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^4 + t^2 + e^{2t}}}, \dfrac{e^t}{\sqrt{t^4 + t^2 + e^{2t}}}, v^2 + \cos(v)\log(v) \right)$$. Is it doable?

Comment: @MatheusAndrade It is actually the *exact same*, all you need is to figure out the range of that function. Instead of a product with a real line, what you get is a product with that range. The reason is that the variable $v$ does not turn up in $x,y$ or $z$.

Comment: I see. But how would I go about actually plotting it in something like Geogebra?

Comment: Oh... I think that's not possible really. Am I right?

Comment: You can't really plot $4$-dimensional things, in any case you would need a good deal of imagination.